# Can't route traffic to VM on corporate Network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to setup an ubuntu virtual machine on my locked down windows pc that my employer gave to me. I have temporary admin access for the next three days only. VM is ubuntu 16 guest running on winddows 7 host.

I have the VM running properly through Virtual box but I cannot get any network activity from within the VM wehn I am on the corporate network for my job. I verified that when I am on regular wifi I can NAT the traffic into the VM with no issues.

As far as I know, my internet connection at work is a non vpn connection that runs through a big corporate firewall. I believe traffic is also proxied through something before it is returned so certain sites can be blocked.

What information would I need to know to ask a more intelligent question about how to configure this or what things could I experiment with to try to get this working

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm not asking a question that is in any way specific to my work, and there is no it department that would help me solve this. I am asking a general question regarding routing traffic to virtual machines. It just happens to be on a corporate network

Comment: "What information would I need to know"  How the router is configured, if and how the firewalls are configured, if and how proxies are configured, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In VirtualBox, the network connection is by default set to NAT. This means that there's a virtual router in place that allows internet traffic to go through, but blocks everything else, unless you open the specific ports.

There are a few routes you can take here. Either open the ports or change the network to a bridged network type. The problem with the last one is, that it will then start to acquire an IP address like a real physical machine and gets registered in the network. It may not be possible to do this in your network.

Opening ports may be what you need to do, but I can't help you with telling you which ports you need to open as that is specific to your situation.

In any case, you will find these settings in the settings page for each VM, under network. You do not have to power down the VM to alter these settings unless you want to add/remove a network interface.

Comment: So if I could view which ports the regular traffic is coming in on and then just open those ports on the VM that might be sufficient?

Comment: Yeah, that might be sufficient. But I'm not sure though, given that your corporate network works with proxies etc. You may need to use the bridged network solution so the network itself handles the traffic to your VM's.